# Postgresql select count(*) takes too long time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table in my postgresql table. The table has about 9.100.000 rows. When I execute a query `select count(*) from table` the execution time is about 1.5 minutes. Is this normal? And what can I do decrease this tim?

Comment: Do you have an index on the primary key?

Comment: @thomas: the primary key always has an index.

Comment: may he hasn't a primary key declared.

Comment: @thomas yas I have id column that is primary key.

Comment: can you try count(id)? Because the primary key can not be null, this has the same result. Maybe postgresql use more memory (and needs more time to read) if you use all columns in the count(*).

Can you provide an execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an estimation of the size you can use count_estimate. It is much faster. 
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

Another workaround is to use a statistics field, to increase it every time a new row is being added.

Also please read https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/